# How to best approach two threads needing one set of data?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, xcode

I need to be able to write data to a chart while simultaneously gathering data. The data cannot be modified while the chart is reading from it. However, I need to be able to get new data while the chart is reading data. The data that is rendered in the chart doesn't need to be 100% up to date.

Here is what I thought:
Data is read into a write array which is locked, the data is then copied into a read array which is also locked, then both are unlocked.
The chart locks the copied array whenever it needs to read it.
The data gatherer reads more data into the read array.
Every once is a while the data gatherer locks both arrays and copies the write array into the read array.

Are there any better ways to do this?